# Is there any way to open Components in the CME without including the Inline editing for content TBB on our CTs in Tridion UI-2012?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

Earlier we were using the SiteEdit 1.3 TBB on our Page Template which enabled us to open Components in the CME without needing to add the SiteEdit 1.3 TBB on each individual Component Template.

Now we have moved to Tridion UI-2012 and added “Enable editing for Page” TBB on our Page Template but it doesn't allow Component to open in the CME. Is there any easier way to do this, rather than editing each individual Component Template?

Comment: I guess Rita is saying, in 1.3 only PT had siteedit tbb, CT doesn't have any SE tbb associated, still there was an option to open component in CME. But in ui-2012 this option is not there, so do all the CTs have to edited to have the SE tbb in UI-2012 or there is some setting which needs to be enabled to get that option.

Answer (score 4):

In short, unfortunately yes, you have to add the "Enable inline editing for content" TBB to every Component Template, for the Components to be marked correctly in Experience Manager.

SiteEdit 1.3 was working different in that sense, the TBB on the Page Template basically marked the Component Presentation, and the TBB on the Component Template was just there for the fields. With UI-2012 (or Experience Manager) there are basically two things:

1. On each Schema field you indicate whether that field should be editable or not
2. By means of the "Enable inline editing for content" TBB you indicate if you want to enable Experience Manager functionality for the Component.

The "Enable inline editing for Page" TBB you place on the Page, only adds the functionality required to the Page, this doesn't relate to the Components anymore. That now gives you the added benefit of having more control over which Component Presentations you want editable on your Page, but every pro might have its cons too.

What you could consider is to simply add the "Enable inline editing for content" TBB to your "Default Finish Actions" TBB. That would save you the trouble of editing all the Component Templates. You will still need to Publish these changes, so in effect it isn't much of a difference (I personally would prefer to add the TBB directly in every Component Template, its not going to take you more than a minute or two per CT (you could even consider doing it directly in the CME by editing the XML source of each CT, saves you the time of having to start up the Template Builder) .

Comment: +1, though technically if the page "knows" the components, it could still add the wrapping SiteEdit markup but manually, right? I'd still recommend updating component templates, though--there are a lot of useful features by enabling inline editing in XPM.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `"Open in Form View"` available in the Experience Manager toolbar that can be used to open your component in the CME Component View.

Comment: It's a pretty big button too :)

Comment: Thanks Eric for your reply, but my question was different. we can use command "open in Form View" when we select the component. But without adding SE tbb in CT we are not able to select any component, so also not able to use "open in Form View" command in XPM. In 1.3 only PT had siteedit tbb, CT doesn't have any SE tbb associated, still we were able to get selection area around the component and there was an option to open component in CME. But in ui-2012 this option is not there, so do all the CTs have to edited to have the SE tbb in UI-2012 or is there some setting which we need to enable?